# Error en la prueba de cargar un cardview en una lista

Tags: android

el error esta en que al seleccionar la opción tarea abre la ventana donde selecciono un grupo ya revise el adapatador no encuentro el error

dejo un link con el video de la ejecución de la app

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUciumCv78w

también el github donde pueden descargar la aplicación

https://github.com/Austin52/App_Doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el método onBindViewHolder(..) de la clase TareaAdaptador estás pasando al TextView myViewHolder.grdTarea un entero y da error ya que sólo admite String.

Puedes corregirlo añadiendo String.valueOf(..):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TareaAdaptador.myViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

    myViewHolder.grdTarea.setText(String.valueOf(mDate.get(i).getGrdTarea()));
    //...

}
```